# A very tricky integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to integrate

$$
\int \frac{11\sec^2\theta\tan^2\theta}{\sqrt{49-\tan^2\theta}}d\theta
$$

and I am continually getting the wrong answer. I would like steps in solving this problem

Comment: $$ \int\frac {11 \tan^2\theta}{\sqrt{49 - \tan^2\theta}} \Big( \sec^2\theta\,d\theta\Big)  \text{ (So } \sec^2\theta\,d\theta \text{ becomes } du.) $$

Comment: Type (11sec²(x)tan²(x))/(49-tan²(x))^(1/2) into www.integral-calculator.com for a FULL explanation after you click “show steps”

Answer (score 11):

**HINT**

Make the substitution $\displaystyle u = \frac{\tan(\theta)}{7}$.

Comment: that $49$ was a dead giveaway, wasn't it?

Answer (score 2):

$\int\dfrac{11\sec^2\theta\tan^2\theta}{\sqrt{49-\tan^2\theta}}~d\theta
$

$=\int\dfrac{11\tan^2\theta}{\sqrt{49-\tan^2\theta}}~d(\tan\theta)
$

$=\int\dfrac{11x^2}{\sqrt{49-x^2}}~dx$ $(\text{Let}~x=\tan\theta)$

$=\int77\sin^2\phi~d\phi$ $(\text{Let}~x=7\sin\phi)$

$=\int\dfrac{77-77\cos2\phi}{2}~d\phi$

$=\dfrac{77\phi}{2}-\dfrac{77\sin2\phi}{4}+C$

$=\dfrac{77\phi}{2}-\dfrac{77\sin\phi\cos\phi}{2}+C$

$=\dfrac{77}{2}\sin^{-1}\dfrac{x}{7}-\dfrac{11x\sqrt{49-x^2}}{14}+C$

$=\dfrac{77}{2}\sin^{-1}\dfrac{\tan\theta}{7}-\dfrac{11\sqrt{49-\tan^2\theta}\tan\theta}{14}+C$